# Push notifications do not work

Tags: ios, swift

I use Firebase cloud message. I had pod ‘FirebaseInstanceID’, ‘= 1.0.2’, and then I updated it to = 2.0.4. Now I'm getting InstanceID.instanceID().token(), and APN.

After I updated my version of FirebaseInstanceID, my notifications no longer work, I don't understand why.

I also added  ‘GoogleService-Info.plist’.

my pod
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod ‘FirebaseInstanceID’, ‘= 2.0.4’
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
        FirebaseApp.configure()

    Messaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

//Notifiction
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    openScreenFromPush(userInfo: userInfo)
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    openScreenFromPush(userInfo: userInfo)

    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

// [END receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(token)")
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        openScreenFromPush(userInfo: userInfo)

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for some reason you have to put   `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` before FirebaseApp.configure()

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]




        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }




        // [END register_for_notifications]
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)`

in:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }

    print("APNs token retrieved: \(token)")
}
```

Method. And it works